# Particular generators of GL(2,R)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, general-linear-group

I want to prove that $$ \text{GL}_{2}( \mathbb{R} ) = \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}; \ a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \right\rangle  $$ I know that $$ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{k} = \begin{pmatrix} a^{k} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}^{l} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & a^{l} \end{pmatrix},$$$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{m} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{h} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ h & 1\end{pmatrix}. $$ Since the determinant of these matrices isn't zero $ \forall k,l,m,h \in \mathbb{Z}, a \neq 0$, the determinant of a product of any permutation of these matrices isn't zero. Therefore this generates invertible matrices and for $k=l=m=h=0$ we get identity matrix. Is there an efficient way to prove that this generates all invertible two by two matrices over $ \mathbb{R}$ other than checking all possible permutations?

Comment: The informal idea is that these matrices are precisely the ones you need to perform Gauss elimination. If you write the steps of Gauss elimination, each step can be seen as multiplication by one of your above matrices, and at the end you get the identity matrix, so reversing the process gives you a way of expressing any invertible $2\times 2$ matrix as a product of such matrices. One can write a formal proof of this fact, but it is probably harder to write down than to understand why it works

Comment: @LouisHainaut Thank you for the insight. This is an interesting way of looking at the problem. I think I might be able to construct the proof based on this idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @LouisHainaut, these  four matrices enable you to do the elementary row operations.  Since it is possible to get to and from the identity matrix to any invertible matrix by doing elementary row operations, the result follows.

The first two allow you to multiply a row by a scalar.  The last two, to add a multiple of a row to another.